# How to remove deposit from leaky alkaline cell

Tags: batteries, failure

I have an LED torch that must have been left turned on when put aside for some time, so one of the AAA alkaline cells in it has leaked and left a white deposit. It is worthwhile trying to recover the torch, that is I might as well try rather than just throw it away, so I have dismantled it as far as I can and immersed the parts in tap water, in a hard water area, for a couple of days. The deposit on the plastic cell holder has gone, but there is still a hard white deposit inside the metal case. How, please, could I dissolve that away, or soften it so that it will rub away? For instance I might need a mild alkaline or acidic solution, but, if so, which? Or, possibly an organic solvent such as alcohol or acetone?

Comment: Which is the metal that the case is made with? 
I had an old Maglite flashlight that suffered an alkaline cell leakage, the metal from the case is made with aluminium. The steel from the cell and the aluminium made a bond so strong that I never could unscrew the back cap of the flashlight again. In my case, the flashlight got lost. By the way, I don't think an organic solvent can help you, since we're talking about a kind of salt crusted to a metal surface.

Comment: I first use abrasion to remove the crust -- typically a dental tool. The potassium hydroxide, exposed to air, reacts with carbon dioxide to form potassium carbonate (the white crud you see) which is completely insoluable in alcohol. You can use HCl (sold often as muriatic acid), I think, to more quickly remove the crud. (I keep a 30% solution of HCl here.)

Comment: Isopropanol is your friend as always.

Comment: @winny Unfortunately, potassium carbonate is pretty much insoluble in alcohol. See http://www.commonorganicchemistry.com/Common_Reagents/Potassium_Carbonate/Potassium_Carbonate.htm

Comment: two words: steel wool.

Comment: @jonk Oh! Intrersting! I must have been scrubbing and the mechanical force did the trick which led me to belive it was my favorite chemical - isopropanol.

Comment: Sodium carbonate and/or vinegar